# Google customer rating tags no triggering rich snippets in Google search results

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

We previously had a working rating review displayed when you search in Google. This worked for more than a year but has now stopped working for the last couple of weeks.

The mark up that we are using is: We currently have an error in regard to a missing `itemprop="image"` but do not believe this is why it has stopped working. As we have added an image on our test site but this is still not working.

```
  <div class="auradrsmall" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
         <span class="header">Customer Recommendation</span>

    <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
      <span itemprop="name" class="auraGoogleReviewText">Platts Hyundai - High Wycombe</span>
    </div>        
    <span itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <span itemprop="name" class="auraGoogleReviewText">Aura Corporation</span>
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2017-02-02">
         <div class="section">
      <div class="col type">Sales</div>
      <div class="col ratingNumber">4.8</div>
      <div class="col auraratingsmall10" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue" class="auraGoogleReviewText">4.8</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <ul>
          <li>10 Customers</li>
          <li><a href="javascript:openlightbox('UK45199');">6 comments</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

         <div class="section">
      <div class="col type">Service</div>
      <div class="col ratingNumber">4.8</div>
      <div class="col auraratingsmall10"></div>
      <div class="col">
        <ul>
          <li>71 Customers</li>
          <li><a href="javascript:openlightbox('UK45200');">36 comments</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">Real customer reviews from <span class="aura">aura</span> </div>
  </div>
```

Can anybody please tell us if they can see the issue in regard to our mark up and any possible changes in Google structured data or policy?

Comment: Have you run your page through the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)?